# How to fetch checkboxes data from DB using php and jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to display the checkboxes values like if the DB contains the following

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 868
            [username] => Pavanasri
            [firstname] => Pavana
            [email] => pavan@gmail.com
            [signupdate] => 2020-07-13
            [add_topic_priv] => Y
            [add_subject_priv] => Y
            [add_post_priv] => Y
            [add_note_priv] => Y
            [add_disable_priv] => N
            [add_notifications_priv] => Y
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 785
            [username] => sam123
            [firstname] => sam
            [email] => sa@gmail.com
            [signupdate] => 2020-07-23
            [add_topic_priv] => Y
            [add_subject_priv] => Y
            [add_post_priv] => Y
            [add_note_priv] => Y
            [add_disable_priv] => N
            [add_notifications_priv] => Y
        )
)
```

So here I have some fields fetching from the DB and first 5 fields are displaying in the  table . But coming to the checkbox values how can I display the checked values [y] on the front end using jquery. Here is the jquery code.

```
  window.fillData = function(){
  alert("memberslist");
   var gid = $("#proid").val(); 
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        url:"memberslist.php",
        data:{
          gid:gid,
          action:"membersList",
         },
         success : function(response)
        { 
          
          if(response.status=="1")
          {
            response.data.forEach(function(item) {

              if (item.add_topic_priv =="Y")
            {
              $("#topic").is(":checked");
            }
             
            var row = "<tr>";
            row += "<td id=tid>" + item.username + "</td>";
            row += "<td id=firstname>" +item.firstname+ "</td>";
            row += "<td id=email>" + item.email +   "</td>";
            row += "<td id=signupdate>" + item.signupdate + "</td>";
            row += "<td id=invitedon>" + item.invitedon + "</td>";
            row += "<td id=acceptedon>" + item.acceptedon + "</td>";


            row += "<td> <input type=checkbox id=topic name=example2 class=td-check-box> </td>";
            row += "<td> <input type=checkbox id=subject name=example2 class=td-check-box> </td>";
            row += "<td> <input type=checkbox id=post name=example2 class=td-check-box> </td>";
            row += "<td> <input type=checkbox id=note name=example2 class=td-check-box> </td>";
            row += "<td> <input type=checkbox id=disable name=example2 class=td-check-box> </td>";
            row += "<td> <input type=checkbox id=notification name=example2 class=td-check-box> </td>";
            row += "<td><i id=deletep class=\'fa fa-trash-o\'></i></td>";
            row += "</tr>";
            $("#tableid").append(row);
           
            })
          }
        },
            error : function(response){
              $("#succ_msg").html("<p style=\'color:red;font-weight:bolder;\'>error</p>");
            }
          });
          return false;
        }
```

In the above code i am trying to print the fields but coming to the checkboxes it is not display checked for the id of "topic" . How can we fetch checked value to the html through jQuery. So I can Apply to other fields.

Output what i want [image]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check

```
$("#topic").prop("checked", true);
```

To uncheck

```
$("#topic").prop("checked", false);
```

EDIT [contains code for something that was asked later on]

```
          if(response.status=="1")
          {
            
            response.data.forEach(function(item, index) {

            ....

            row += "<td> <input type=checkbox id=topic" + index +  "name=example2 class=td-check-box> </td>";

            ....

            $("#tableid").append(row);

              if (item.add_topic_priv =="Y")
            {
              $("#topic" + index).is(":checked");
            }
           
            })
          }
        },
```

Comment: i have a dynamic values then how can i get the checked if i have Y and if have N then unchecked

Comment: i need to use the if stamtement right then how can i get that

Comment: if(item.add_topic_priv == "Y")
            {
              $("#topic").prop("checked", true);
            }
          else{
            $("#topic").prop("checked", false);

          }@Aashish gaba is this is the correct way'

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Did this work or not?

Comment: yes it is working but in the table i have so many rows based on that it is display for the first column it is showing correct . From the second onwards it is not applying

Comment: I noticed something in your code, you're looping over the array and you're adding the checkbox for all of them, and you want them to be checked or unchecked according to some variable that comes along with it. BUT you have a common id for all those items in the array. You need to have individual ids for them, something like `topic1`, `topic2` where the number is the index number of the element in the array, and then you could use this as `$("#topic"+$i).prop("checked", false);` where $i is the index in the array. I hope I made it clear, if not let me know.

Comment: And yeah, it's not working for rest of them because of the same reason that I mentioned in the previous comment(you are assigning same if to every element of that array)

Comment: Then how can i loop every checbox field that means like while loop for  this code . if(item.add_topic_priv == "Y") { $("#topic").prop("checked", true); } else{ $("#topic").prop("checked", false); } yes I can understood ur explaintion but for every field how can u get the different ids . Can you please explain me how can we  generate unique id for every row topic checkbox @Aashish gaba .

Comment: You can have the different id as `topic` + the index of the iteration of the loop. This way every row gets a unique id. Check the solution, You can add the rows with dynamic id using index in that manner and access the element for checking or unchecking it.

Comment: okay @Aashish gaba I will try now thank you for helping me .

Comment: <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" onLoad="fillData()" href="#members"> MEMBERS </a></li>
I have another doubt in  the above code if I put the onload here then what i need to keep here .  ```window.fillData = function(){```. Actually i wrote this code for the onclick but clicking on the tab the data is displaying repeatedly

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have any idea how to do that :( . And one more thing, try not to keep questions in the comments. Post another question with your doubt, and someone will help you for sure. And with this approach it keeps the questions organized so that later on other people can refer to it.

Comment: Okay sure @Aashish gava tq